# get top 6 reapeating number in 6 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the top 6 repeating numbers in columns A-F , in any order would be fine , tried using `=Mode` but I'm stuck

[image]

Comment: @Jeeped i used =mode(A:F) , it will only returns the most reapting numbers , i dont know how to get the other top 2 to 6

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve the top 6 most repeating numbers from the entire range and then return them in the red cells on the right?

Comment: @girlvsdata I think the op wants the top 6 mode in all 6 columns; like large(a;F, 1), large(a;F, 2), ... large(a;F, 5), large(a;F, 6) but with mode.

Comment: @girlvsdata the same cell or separate cell is fine. a long as its the top 6 repeating numbers on columns A-F

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=TRANSPOSE` and `=MODE.MULT`

This is an array formula, close with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(A:F))
```

And fill across 6 cells to get the top 6 repeating values.

Comment: i did not get it right , god im really new at this : https://prnt.sc/k791c9

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: im using docs.google.com , do i need an installed version on my computer? @girlv

Comment: Google Sheets is not the same as Excel. You won't get all the same formulas across both - this formula will work in Excel, it won't work in Google Sheets.

Comment: @girlsvsdata thank you so much imma try this on another computer.

Comment: No worries, let me know how it goes. If it works for you please mark this as your chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

The MODE function is not the most efficient formula, likely due to some internal cyclic calculation. Cut your full column ranges down to the minimum of what is required for an accuate result.

In K12 as a standard formula,

```
=mode(a:f)
'better as,
=mode($A1:INDEX($F:$F, MATCH(1E+99, $F:$F)))
```

In L12 as an array formula with CSE,

```
=MODE(IF(NOT(COUNTIF($K12:K12, $A1:INDEX($F:$F, MATCH(1E+99, $F:$F)))), $A1:INDEX($F:$F, MATCH(1E+99, $F:$F))))
```

Fill L12 right to P12.

[image]

---

<sub>Recommended: [MINIF, MAXIF and MODEIF](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd)</sub>